# PHP: is urlencode() a safe way to allow valid UTF-8 strings in the URL?

Tags: php, url, utf-8

I have user submitted tags that can be any type of (valid) UTF-8 string. I want to know if it is safe to include them in the URL merly by running them through `urlencode()`.

In other words, is urlencode() safe to use for valid UTF-8 strings?
(by valid I mean id have already force-encoded them to UTF-8)

Comment: try looking here... http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php there is some discussion down the page see the post by "dominik dot hofer at gmx dot net" it may help

Comment: Dominik's issue ( http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php#88712 ) seems to actually be with the fact that the resulting string was not safe for javascript/html.  Which brings up a good question for Xeoncross: when you mean "safe", do you mean "URL safe", or "URL safe and HTML safe"?  Because if you want html safe, you'll need to use htmlentities() in addition to urlencode.

Comment: As far as I know, you shouldn't do `urlencode` when putting an URL in an `<a href="">` attribute. That's the browser's job. Just do `htmlspecialchars`.

Comment: Well, the URL's will be embedded in the page HTML as links. For regular content: If you're sending the UTF-8 header, and your content is a valid UTF-8 string that has been run through `htmlspecialchars()` - then your safe. It is only invalid UTF-8 strings, or no UTF-8 header that pose a problem.

Comment: @Nicolás I wasn't aware the that browser would handle that on it's own. If that is true then I'll just run my URL's through `htmlspecialchars` just like the rest of my code. Please submit that as an answer if you are sure.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode) does not depend on a specific character encoding. It just looks at the bytes, interprets them as ASCII characters and replaces any byte that is either not allowed in ASCII (0x80–0xFF) or not allowed in plain in a URL.

Now to your question: Yes, using `urlencode` does encode any string in any character encoding to be safely used – but only in the URL query! Because `urlencode` formats the input according to [*application/x-www-form-urlencoded*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1) that differs from the “normal” [percent encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1) in how the space is encoded: In *application/x-www-form-urlencoded* spaces are replaced by `+` while the “normal” percent encoding replaces them by `%20`.

If you want to “normal” percent encoding use [`rawurlencode`](http://php.net/rawurlencode) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `urlencode()` should make a safe URL string out of any input string.  As long as whatever that URL is mapping to `(folder/file/htaccess)`, doesn't have funky characters in it.  Whenever sanitizing stuff from a user where they could be posting something funky I love this function:

`utf8_encode()`

Comment: Sorry, utf8_encode() is not a safe function. It is only meant to be used for safe strings (which user input is not).

Comment: Huh... didn't realize that.  Thanks!  Right now i'm using that function to clean up the data coming right from a wordpress database.  Its the only function I found that would take out those funky characters that wordpress puts in there (like double space, styled quotes).  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just to be entirely on the safe side, I would remove newlines first. They are not dangerous in themselves, but they can be stepping stones in exploiting other vulnerabilities.